# How do you distinguish between an iOS app entering background via the press of lock button vs otherwise?

Tags: ios9, mpnowplayinginfocenter

In my app I want to show Now Playing Info on the lockscreen, if the app is still the main one when lock screen button is pressed. But I don't want to show the info if the app was backgrounded through switching to another app or via press of home button.

Either case triggers resign active and did enter background, how do you distinguish between an iOS app entering background via the press of lock screen vs otherwise?

Comment: Hello. I am finding same question to you.
Did you find solution about that?